# Sharepoint look and feel

Tags: site

I am trying to change the look & feel of the site & I have tried to apply theme already provided by Microsoft SharePoint but I am using custom master page & the change of theme applies to the default master page so my changes gets overwritten & it gives the default master page. Can anyone please guide me how to apply themes on custom master page.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did it work for you

Comment: Its working but not as expected output. Not too much nice themes

Comment: So your question of how to apply themes on custom master page is answered. You can create another question to ask how to customise your own theme.

Answer (score 1):

When you go to Site settings > Change the look, you're looking at different *Composed Looks*.

Every Composed Look has associated with it a:

- Master page
- Theme (i.e. colour scheme)
- Background image
- Font scheme

When you select one of the out-of-box composed looks from the "Change the look" page you're going back to using one of the default master pages.

So, you need to create your own Composed Look by going to Site settings > Composed looks > New item. Be sure to select your master page here. For the other fields, like Theme URL, you can just reuse what's already in another Composed Look that you like the look of. Save it.

You should now see your newly created Composed look show up on the "Change the look" page.